# Apache WSGI Python 0 bypass python file token access

Tags: python, apache, token, wsgi

I want to use apache to feed the file to client bypassing python
but file should be available only to python authorized user.

for example
i have a file /uploads/user/somepic.jpg
& i want to make this file accessible only to currently logged in user

maybe by some address like /downloads/#some_hash#
bypassing pythons yield f.read(),
is it possible and can someone point me to the right direction?
i couldn't find anything to start with.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish "bypassing" python for the file but not for authentication?

Comment: What sort of authentication? To do this for Basic authenticaion is easy. Form based authentication a bit harder and potentially requires some addition modules to Apache.